# Supporting IE8 with Angular JS, React JS, and Breeze JS

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-8, reactjs, breeze

I know that each of the following packages can individually work with IE8:

Angular JS (upto version 1.3), React JS, and Breeze JS

However using Breeze and Angular together does not within IE8 as discussed in detail [Breeze and Angular 'ToDo' app does not work with IE 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14238134/breeze-and-angular-todo-app-does-not-work-with-ie-8)

Is there any experience using React with Breeze within an Angular App to support IE8?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

React + breeze wont work on IE8 for the same reason that angular + breeze wont work there: lack of support for `Object.definedProperty`.

We do not plan to make further attempts to overcome deficiencies of IE8.

Comment: Ward, thank you for taking the time to answer. We use breeze everyday in our organisation - with Durandal :) - so thanks for bringing it to the masses.